# UI Error in Android Using Google map apiv2 Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, google-maps-api-2

I have used Google map API v2 in my project, in the layout file I used the following code I attached. It is working perfectly but in UI design a black layer is form when scroll the activity

[image]

**code:**

```
<ScrollView
-----
--->

<LinearLayout
-----
----->
//bla bla bla
<fragment
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mapview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
         map:cameraZoom="15"
       />

//bla bla bla
</LinearLayout
-----
----->
</ScrollView
-----
--->
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution  is to use the new `GoogleMap.snapshot()` function, and using a screenshot of the map instead; as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18212473/495800).