# Android v2 MapFragment shaking when scrolling in Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-maps-v2

I am using the SupportMapFragment to display a static map in a ScrollView. I do not like to move / zoom the Map, just showing where the location is.

When I am scrolling down/up the map shakes inside its bounds, it feels pretty laggy. My question is, how is ist possible to remove this lag, or how to use a static version of the v2 api map.

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_half"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  ...

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMap"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewDivider"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_half"

         />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fragmentMap"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fragmentMap"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/fragmentMap"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/fragmentMap"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

   ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is not really related to [MapFragment in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746351/mapfragment-in-scrollview), even though i used this trick to remove the black clipping on older devices, as you can see with the transparent view.

I also disabled all gestures and the click-ability of the maps view:

```
getMap().getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
getMap().getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
getMap().getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

...
mapView.setClickable(false);
mapView.setFocusable(false);
mapView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new release of the Google Play Services, Google added a [snapshot](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) method in order to retrieve a Bitmap of the currenrt shown map, which instead may be shown. So interaction is not possible but at leased the map is not shaking anymore.

use

```
GoogleMap.snapshot (GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback)
```

and implement the SnapshotReadyCallback. Once the Snapshot is delivered, replace the MapFragment with an ImageView containing the Snapshot.

This example works pretty well in the onResume method:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        notifyDataChanged();
        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = fragmentMap.getView()
                .getViewTreeObserver();

        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver
                    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            onMesuredMap(this);
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    private void onMesuredMap(OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
        if (fragmentMap.getView().getWidth() != 0
                && fragmentMap.getView().getHeight() != 0) {

            fragmentMap.getView().getViewTreeObserver()
                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);

            makeSnapShot();
        }
    }

        private void makeSnapShot() {
    Runnable action = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            fragmentMap.getMap().snapshot(new SnapshotReadyCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap arg0) {
                    imageViewStaticMap.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                    removeMapFragment();
                }

            });
        }
    };
            //litle hack to make sure that the map is loaded for sure
    fragmentMap.getView().postDelayed(action, 1500);
}

    private void removeMapFragment() {
        if (fragmentMap.isVisible()) {
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .remove(fragmentMap)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

**Sidenote:**
To use the new release run an Update of the Android SDK Manager, and when using maven run the [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) with:

```
mvn install -fae
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this class, it should look better at least when scrolling right and left in our scrollview:

```
public class TransparentSupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    public TransparentSupportMapFragment() {

        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view, Bundle savedInstance) {

        View layout = super.onCreateView(inflater, view, savedInstance);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        ((ViewGroup) layout).addView(frameLayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not solve the vertical scrolling lag, but it is a more beautiful solution of the transparent overlay. Thanks.

Comment: About your issu i don't see a solution for now, i've always used google map in full screen in an activity

Comment: This is bad news. Maybe I will use API v1 again.